# Basecamp API Calendar Event Dates

Tags: calendar, basecamp

I am trying to create a calendar event for a project but the dates for the calendar event are not being properly set.

Here is the JSON data I am passing to the service

```
{
 "summary":"New Calendar Item #2",
 "description":"Details to follow",
 "all_day":"false",
 "starts_at":"2015-05-07T00:00:00.0000000",
 "ends_at":"2015-05-12T00:00:00.0000000",
 "remind_at":"2015-05-06T00:00:00.0000000",
 "subscribers":"all",
 "private":"false"
}
```

After I POST that information to the "new" Basecamp API the dates are not correct.  Here are the dates that I receive back for the newly created Calendar Event:

```
 "starts_at":"2015-05-06T20:00:00.000-04:00",
 "ends_at":"2015-05-06T20:00:00.000-04:00",
 "remind_at":"2015-05-05T20:00:00.000-04:00"
```

Not sure why the date values are off.  I am assuming the dates are in proper format since I am not getting a 400 status code back.

Any help would be appreciated.

Here is a link to their documentation:
https://github.com/basecamp/bcx-api/blob/master/sections/calendar_events.md

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you change the format of the `starts_at`, `ends_at` and `reminds_at` to the following, you should get the times you expect:

```
 "starts_at":"2015-05-07T00:00:00-00:00",
 "ends_at":"2015-05-12T00:00:00-00:00",
 "remind_at":"2015-05-06T00:00:00-00:00",
```

You could pass the timezone of the user instead if the event is to start at midnight local time:

```
 "starts_at":"2015-05-07T00:00:00-04:00",
 "ends_at":"2015-05-12T00:00:00-04:00",
 "remind_at":"2015-05-06T00:00:00-04:00",
```

Comment: I tried to post the exact values you placed in your response.  Here is the JSON I post:
'
{"summary":"New Calendar Item #2","description":"Details to follow","all_day":false,"starts_at":"2015-05-07T00:00:00-00:00","ends_at":"2015-05-12T00:00:00-00:00","remind_at":"2015-05-06T00:00:00-00:00","subscribers":"all","private":false}
'

I am still not getting the right dates.  Here are the dates I am getting back:
'
"starts_at":"2015-05-06T20:00:00.000-04:00","ends_at":"2015-05-06T20:00:00.000-04:00","remind_at":"2015-05-05T20:00:00.000-04:00"
'

Any other suggestions?  I am stumped :)

Comment: I found out that if I want the event to span over a couple of days you need to set the "all_day" flag to be "true".  I was setting it to be false.  However if I set the "all_day" flag to be true and I want the event to start at a specific time it does not let you do that.  It will drop off the start time.